# XSLT 2.0: regex extract and modify element value

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<xml>
   <row>
      <image><![CDATA[javascript: open_window_zoom('http://example.com/image.php?image=/images/test/example.png&pID=46391&download=noid_90.png&name=Test name', 975, 366);]]></image>
      <quantity>0</quantity>
   </row>
   <row>
      <image><![CDATA[javascript: open_window_zoom('http://example.com/image.php?image=/images/test/another.png&pID=06395&download=anotherfile.png&name=Test name', 975, 366);]]></image>
      <quantity>0</quantity>
   </row>
</xml>
```

It is possible to extract `pID=NUMBERHERE&download=FILENAMEHERE.png` (and add new url before it)from `<image>` element?

The output should be like this:

```
<xml>
   <row>
      <image>http://newurl.com/pID=46391&download=noid_90.png</image>
      <quantity>0</quantity>
   </row>
   <row>
      <image>http://newurl.com/pID=06395&download=anotherfile.png</image>
      <quantity>0</quantity>
   </row>
</xml>
```

I tried some things, but I can't get the desidered result. For start I can copy the current structure:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What about `(?<=&)pID[^&']+`? Match everything after `&pID` until a `&` or `'` is reached. Doesn't include the initial `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet splits the value by `&` and then uses a predicate to filter only those that [`matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) the supplied regex where the parameter names are either pID or download. Using the @separator for xsl:value-of to join the values with `&`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>http://newurl.com/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '&amp;')[matches(., '(pID|download).*')]" 
                          separator="&amp;"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, this XSLT 2.0 stylesheet uses [`xsl:analyze-string`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string) to extract the text that matches the provided regex:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>http://newurl.com/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=".*(pID=.*&amp;download=.*)&amp;.*">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring></xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, both solution are great. One more question: can you please write me an example to how to change the download= parameter into image= in the output?

Answer (score 2):

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="image">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://newurl.com/pID=', substring-before(substring-after(text(), '&amp;pID='), '&amp;name='))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```